# Allure + pytest, генерирует JSON файлы

Tags: python, pytest, allure

Всем доброго времени суток. Гоняю тесты Python 3.7 + pytest + selenium. Появилась необходимость прикрутить читабельные отчёты, выбор пал на allure.

Но почему то Allure генерирует не XML  а JSON файлы и при попытке их сгенерить в html выдаёт ошибку.

Использую Pycharm + в конфиге --alluredir=path/to/report + pytest + allure-pytest.
Так же установил allure-comandline.

Ниже содержимое одного отчёта (их два на один тест)

```
{"name": "test_one", "status": "passed", "steps": 
[{"name": "test_one", "status": "passed", "parameters": 
[{"name": "setup_driver_chrome", "value": "<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session=\"ce03f5b09014d54a7a97d40393662f00\")>"}],
"start": 1572359648704, "stop": 1572359652539}],
"start": 1572359648704, "stop": 1572359652539,
"uuid": "80998b41-a358-4fef-a885-07362212610a", "historyId": "eaa6c1834b37e8afdd35a4a0fa4abc41", "testCaseId": "b607463ae5af74e8880d621157e6d846",
"fullName": "test_1#test_one", "labels": [{"name": "suite", "value": "test_1"}, {"name": "host",
"value": "whitespider-Lenovo-ideapad-510S-13ISK"},
{"name": "thread", "value": "32530-MainThread"},
{"name": "framework", "value": "pytest"}, {"name": "language", "value": "cpython3"}, {"name": "package", "value": "test_1"}]}
```

Тест пробный:

```py
def test_one(setup_driver_chrome):
        setup_driver_chrome.get('https://yandex.ru/')
        input = setup_driver_chrome.find_element_by_id('text')
        input.send_keys('pytnon')
        input.submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решён, allure и должен генерить JSOn файлы.
Проблемой при запуске было то, что я устанавливал allure через репозиторий, который не обновлялся + старая версия не поддерживала Java 11, установленный у меня.
После ручной установки, всё заработало через команду `allure serve path/to/allure_json`
При попытке сгенерить отчёт командой `allure generate` отчёт открывается пустым, это связано с тем, что браузеры не подгружают данные с диска ajax запросами, поэтому необходимо их опубликовывать через local сервер.